# Ubuntu - copy MBR from flash to CD

Tags: ubuntu, mbr

I've MBR on a flash drive, how can I copy it to CD?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=mbr.bin bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

Then copy the MBR.BIN to a CDROM or whatever.

Said that, what you ask doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: unfortunately this way I can copy MBR from one flash drive to another, but it doesn't work for CD (it's not bootable).

BTW I cannot overwrite MBR on my HDD, beacuse it would broke Pointsec, which is used to encrypt a Windows partition.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do? What OS do you want to boot and how?

Answer (score 0):

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/CD-Writing-HOWTO-3.html have a look at it. You just need a console cd burner